# PHP include(); not including file

Tags: php, html

I am trying to include a separate snippet of code to fetch data from MySQL tables. My page code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
    <?php include('head.php'); ?>
    <body>
        <?php include('navigation.php'); ?>
        <div id="container">
        <?php
            $section = "Movies";
            print "THIS IS A TEST";
            //$_SESSION['sectiontemp'] = $section;
            include('section-grabinfo.php');
            include('footer.php');
        ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My **section-grabinfo.php** page:

```
<?php
            print "THIS IS A TEST";
            $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM article JOIN person ON article.author=person.id WHERE section='".$section."' AND status=1 ORDER BY aid DESC LIMIT 1;");
            if ($sql == 'false') {
                print "SQL doesn't work";
            }
            elseif ($sql == 'true') {
                print "Works all fine";
            }
            else {
                print "Wrong code.";
            }
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
                $title = $row['title'];
                $preview = $row['preview'];
                $author = $row['name'];
                $person_id = $row['author'];
                $id = $row['id'];
                $username = $row['username'];
                include('featured-article.php');
            }
            //LEAVE SPACE FOR ADS
?>
<div id="secondaryArticleSection">
<?php
            $sql2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM article JOIN person ON article.author=person.id WHERE aid<(SELECT max(aid) FROM article WHERE section='."$section."' AND status=1) AND section='".$section."' AND status=1 ORDER BY aid DESC;");
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {
                $title = $row['title'];
                $preview = $row['preview'];
                $author = $row['name'];
                $person_id = $row['author'];
                $id = $row['id'];
                $username = $row['username'];
                include('secondary-article.php');
            }
?>
</div>
```

Basically my problem is that **section-grabinfo.php** and **footer.php** are not being included on the main page. Please keep in mind that this worked completely when I had this on my laptop computer (not the server I'm currently working with). Thank you.

Comment: By the way, the "THIS IS A TEST" prints out fine.

Comment: So what is wrong exactly ?

Comment: section-grabinfo.php and footer.php are not being included on the main page.

Comment: We need your directory structure

Comment: /public_html/[PAGE NAME]. All three files are in the same directory.

Comment: And if ther's any error message?......It is not the problem oh your code, it is the problem of your directory structure.

Comment: why are you including secondary-article.php file in loop?

Comment: No error messages (turned on all error reporting).

Comment: @JayeshChitroda should I use 'include_once();?'

Comment: @user6559259 yes use include_once()

Comment: all files in same directory ?

Comment: All files are in the same folder: /public_html/ @jothi

Comment: **UPDATE:** I got `footer.php` to be included. Now all that's left is `section-grabinfo.php`

Comment: Can we please try to figure out how to also include `section-grabinfo.php`?

Comment: try this include('./secondary-article.php');

Answer (score 1):

If it is really an including trouble, you could try to include this way

```
<?php include(__DIR__.'/head.php'); ?>
```